# VBA Code doesn't work on all excel sheets

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

**Setting:**

- Using VBA in Access
- Exporting four tables as four sheets in one new excel file with DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport
- modify the exported file withing vba code in access

**What I want to do:**

- There are four sheets in the excel file. In every sheet on all filled columns the "textToColumn" function should be applied.

**The Problem:**

- Making the first row bold works on every sheet.
  "textToColumn" functions only work on the first sheet.

**My Code:**

```
Dim xlApp As Object
Dim xlSheet As Object

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlSheet = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\jfrick\Documents\BPM Access\Revenue Evolution GFS.xlsx")

With xlApp
        .Application.Cells.Select
        .Application.Selection.ClearFormats
        .Application.Rows("1:1").Select
        .Application.Selection.Font.Bold = True
        .Application.Cells.Select
        .Application.Selection.RowHeight = 12.75
        .Application.Selection.Columns.AutoFit

        .Application.Range("E:E").TextToColumns
        .Application.Range("F:F").TextToColumns             
        .Application.ActiveWorkbook.Save
        .Application.ActiveWorkbook.Close
        .Quit
End With
```

I also tried using the following code snippet but this also only changes the columns in the first sheet:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In xlApp.Worksheets 'also tried xlSheet.Worksheets but same result
    ws.Application.Range("E:E").TextToColumns
    ws.Application.Range("F:F").TextToColumns
Next ws
```

**--> How can i apply the "textToColumn" function on the columns in every sheet?**

Comment: would you mind to open Task Manager and tell me, how many Excel processes do you have after running your macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there, just a simple misconception:

Change this:

```
For Each ws In xlApp.Worksheets 'also tried xlSheet.Worksheets but same result
    ws.Application.Range("E:E").TextToColumns
    ws.Application.Range("F:F").TextToColumns
Next ws
```

To this:

```
For Each ws In xlApp.Worksheets
    ws.Range("E:E").TextToColumns
    ws.Range("F:F").TextToColumns
Next ws
```

Since you're referring to `ws.Application.Range` in your attempt, you're calling `.Range` on the application object and not the worksheet object, which refers to the active worksheet, not `ws`